# AWS login authentication through github.com credentails

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, credentials

In Jenkins, we've setup github.com credentials as a authentication for Jenkins login (using the GitHub Authentication Plugin).

Along the same lines, we would like to setup AWS authentication through github.com credentials.

Is there an easy way to setup AWS login authentication through github.com credentials?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ssh keys to access github and ssh keys to access AWS EC2 instances then you could use the same set of keys to access both resources

However, this is not usually considered to be a great idea for security